# Hard Links Not Updating when I Rerun STATA script

Tags: windows, windows-11, symbolic-link, hardlink, microsoft-surface-pro

I have created a hard and symbolic between the output file for one  STATA script to the input file for the next script. I would like that when I run the first script and the output file is updated the target file also updates as is expected with hardlinks. However, the target file never updates. I initially had my folders under dropbox, and I thought that may be the problem so I moved them to my local system but that did not help. I have read that some programs may save updates to files by removing the old one and saving a new version which may break the link. I am not sure if this is the case for STATA.  Does anyone know how I can get the symbolic link to work?
Here is the command I ran for creating the hardlink

```
C:\Users\[File Path]\Tasks_EMOP>mklink /H "C:\Users\[Path]\Consumption_By_Season_Cleaning\Input\emop_despenses_2011_2019_cl.dta" "C:\Users\[File Path]\Appending_Raw_Datasets\Output\emop_despenses_2011_2019_cl.dta"
```

Here is the script saving to the input file

```
* Geographical info
rename Region, lower
label var region "Region"
label define REGION 8 "Kidal", modify
rename Cercle circle 
label var circle "Cirlce" // What's this?
rename Arrond borough
label var borough "Borough"
rename Commune town
label var town "Town"
rename Milieu urban
recode urban (2=0)
label def MILIEU 0 "Rural", modify
label var urban "Urban or rural"

egen tot_exp = rowtotal(consom_total_s1 consom_total_s2 consom_total_s3 consom_total_s4), missing 
label var tot_exp "Total HH expenditure (CFA)"
 
*keep hhid year cluster region circle borough town urban tot_exp taille_men

* For 2014 and 2016 ciricle, borough, and town are completely missing
preserve
use "$input/emop_indivitus_2011_2019_cl.dta", clear
keep iid hhid year region circle borough town
collapse (firstnm)  region circle borough town, by(hhid year)
keep if year == 2011 | year == 2013 | year == 2014 | year == 2016
tempfile geo_vars
save `geo_vars'
restore

merge 1:1 hhid year using `geo_vars', update replace
drop _merge

* For R users
gen region_id = region
gen circle_id = circle 
gen borough_id =  borough
gen town_id = town

* Check duplicates
duplicates report hhid cluster region circle borough town year // None
rename hhid idmenage

save "$output/emop_despenses_2011_2019_cl.dta", replace
// save "C:\[filepath]\Tasks_EMOP\Consumption_By_Season_Cleaning\Input\emop_despenses_2011_2019_cl.dta", replace
```

Screenshot of Original File Location
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lGxe.png

Screenshot of Target File Location

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v1bL.png

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: My bad. Added the script in the body of the question now.